# Symfony2 Form Anchors

Tags: symfony, anchor

I have a number of forms on the one page under different tabs

After the form is processed, I would like to return to the same tab as the form was sent from.

Basically, I would like to modify the target_route to go to the current page with an Anchor at the end of the URL. (EG company/view/6#editdetails)

Could someone provide or link to an example that I can put in my controller or into twig?

Comment: Include the hash in the form `action` attribute already, then users will get back to there after the form is processed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simply:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType($contact), $contact, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'action' => '#editdetails'
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also set this in the template itself as an attribute. See example:

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr: { novalidate: "novalidate", class: 'requiredStar', action: '#form' }}) }}
```